Clustering annotations - Flutter_mapkit_js
anyone knows how to make clustering annotations with the flutter_mapkit_js library; here the documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_mapkit_js/latest/flutter_mapkit_js/flutter_mapkit_js-library.html
Im expecting to make clustering annotations, with the library given before; but i dont find the method to make this
